# shibboleth 5 openldap login

Tags: ldap, openldap

My Environment:

- Shibboleth 5 IdP configured to run inside Jetty 11 servlet (no apache)
- openldap (on same server)
- mod_auth_mellon SP on various dev servers

I have gotten the IdP itself working.  I received a 401 unauthorized error trying to navigate to a SAML managed location on a dev server.  This proves the SAML handshake between SP and IdP is working.

My question is:  What Shibboleth 5 configuration do I need to make to have the IdP display a LDAP login page when the SP redirects back to the IdP for authentication?

I began by following the Shibboleth 5 wiki for installation.  It is not nearly complete.
I have spent weeks scouring the web for Shibboleth and LDAP tutorials.
None exist for Shibboleth 5.
So, I cobbled together what I could from Shibboleth 3 tutorials doing my best to adapt the configs to Shib 5.

I'm not sure which config files will be relevant, so I'll include them as they are asked for.

Comment: "I received a 401 unauthorized error trying to navigate to a SAML managed location" doesn't sound anything like the SAML handshake working! Do you at least get the 401 from the IdP, or is it the SP itself that's reporting the 401? (If it were actually working, the SP would already be redirecting you to the login page as that's kind of the _core functionality_ of the IdP...)